# WP7: Button Tap event does not fire each time

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am having an issue where my button (having an image background) does not fire Tap event each time I tap it on screen (sometimes it fires every time, sometimes once in 3-4 times I tap the button on  screen). Project is targeted for WP7.1.

Button is defined in XAML as:

```
<Button x:Name="Menu" Tap="Menu_Tap" Height="70" Width="70" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MenuImageButtonStyle}"></Button>
```

Style to define menu background image:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuImageButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="StartButtonImage" Source="/Images/menu_button.png" Height="33" Width="33" />
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content=""/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Note that I've experimented by using Tap, Click and ManipulationStarted events, but no luck, all events fire erratically. 
I am quite sure the issue is not my tapping precision, I make sure to tap at the center of the button. I've tested on Nokia Lumia 800.

Entire project code is available here:
http://notecase.sourceforge.net/temp/wp7Issue.zip

Any idea, why is this so? Any tip to fix this?

Comment: My problem seems to be similar to this guy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsRtofL9DQA   Could this be related to hardware?

Comment: I seem to have found a workaround:<br>1. add the following line in page constructor<br>Touch.FrameReported += new TouchFrameEventHandler(Touch_FrameReported);<br>2. Add the required handler:<br>void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)<br>
        {<br>
            TouchPoint ppoint = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(null);<br>
            if (ppoint != null )<br>
            {<br>
                if (Menu.IsMouseOver && ppoint.Action == TouchAction.Down)<br>
                {<br>
                    MessageBox.Show("Tap on Menu");<br>
                }<br>

Comment: To make a more readable comment: I seem to have found a workaround by using a low-level Touch.FrameReported event. You can see the sample here: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_silverlight/article.php/c18445/Windows-Phone-7-Quick-Tutorials-Part-7--Touch.htm